# Creating custom parameter entry UI for Birt in an RCP application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, birt

I want to use BIRT in an RCP application. I'll need to allow the user to enter parameter values and it's a requirement that the parameter entry UI must be customizable by users without compilation.

Is the only way to build a custom parameter JSP page and show it in an embedded browser? Or are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the custom jsp, you can build your own SWT-UI that asks in your RCP for parameter values. You have to

1. parse the rptdesign file by BIRTS API to examine the parameter-types
2. prompt for example your custom dialog and
3. afterwards opening an embedded browser with the entered parameters (the parameters are appended to the URL of the ReportViewer), see also http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerUsage.php#parameters

Comment: Right, the problem is creating the custom dialog which is user-modifiable :) I guess I could try using XWT or some alternative...

Comment: What is exactly the problem creating a custom-dialog?